# Array to populate dropdowns, key isn't working

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having problems filling my dropdown box with the correct array values, which leads to another problem: Dynamically filling a 2nd dropdown box with the children of the appropriate selected parent value.

I have a functions file doing this:

```
$getDisplays = "
SELECT *
FROM locations l
inner join displays d
ON d.location_id = l.id;";

$displayResult = $mysqlConn->query($getDisplays);

$displayNames = array();
foreach($displayResult as $subArray) {
  if(!array_key_exists($subArray['location_name'], $displayNames)) {
    $displayNames[$subArray['location_name']] = array();

  }
    $displayNames[$subArray['location_name']][] = $subArray['display_name'];
}
```

And in my html file I do this:

```
<label for="plantSelect">Select A Location</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="plantSelect">
    <?php foreach($displayNames as $displayName):?>
    <option><?php echo key($displayName)?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </select>
```

That first dropdown contains the correct number of elements but they all just have a zero.

This is the array when dumped:

```
Array
(
[Office 1] => Array
    (
        [0] => lobby
        [1] => break room
    )

[Office 2] => Array
    (
        [0] => lobby
        [1] => break room
    )

[Office 3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Main Conference Room
        [1] => Common Area
    )

[Office 4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Break Room
        [1] => Lobby
        [2] => Line 2
    )

[Office 5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Break Room
        [1] => Lobby
        [2] => Line 1
    )

)
```

So my first dropdown should have Office 1 through 5, and when selected, a 2nd dropdown should fill with the child elements.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `<option>` tag needs a `value=""` attribute. Only that is returned to the PHP on submit

Comment: Also the `<select>` tag needs a `name=""` attribute or nothing is returned to the PHP on submit.

Comment: It seems like YOU have accepted a project that only WE are capable of delivering!

Comment: But that still doesn't answer why the array values aren't loading correctly. I'm expecting the office names as keys and while I get 5 elements in the select, they all just show zero (0)

Comment: See comment number 1

Comment: I mean, is this site not here to help? I've put about 80 hours into this project, I'm on a horrible time crunch and things are being added every day that are convoluted and backwards, but I'm trying to keep it all in check with what I know to do and what's being requested

Comment: Hay! Dont panic!! I did not Vote to Close or DownVote. But all your questions today seem fairly basic but your requirement not so much. We are here to help, but SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: ^ Nor is it really the ideal place to go if you are "on a horrible time crunch". You're never guaranteed a correct answer (or any answer for that matter), and we're here giving our time freely.

Comment: I understand, sorry I wasn't intending to sound rough. I understand where you're coming from and I guess, even though they are pretty basic, I'm used to submitting forms but not when they're passing values from other pages. I guess my point is, I'm used to doing things a certain way and this project is doing some things that weren't accounted for when we started it. I do appreciate all your feedback though!

Comment: @PatrickQ I understand, and I apologize for how that came across. Usually when I'm on a time crunch like this I not only post here, but I also try to consult colleagues and mentors but I just try to cover as many bases as possible, not just to have an answer provided with a full solution, but any bit of guidance for a way to do something differently always helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) returns the current position of the pointer of the array passed to the function.  In your example, you are passing in `displayName`, and the position of the pointer in that array is always 0 when you call it because you aren't iterating over that array.  A better solution would be...

```
<?php foreach($displayNames as $key => $displayName):?>
<option><?php echo $key; ?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Note that if this is being submitted as part of a form (you mention a dynamic correlated dropdown, so maybe you're using ajax instead), then you should heed Riggs' advice.

Comment: Just ran this and it worked perfectly! I was under the impression it would return the value assigned as the key but not the position. Thank yoU!

Comment: At least he remembers to give an accept and maybe even an upvote. :)

Comment: Dont you need the `$key` in the option as a value as well `<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $key; ?></option>`

Comment: @RiggsFolly That was the point of the sentence below the code.  I'm not sure what the specific use-case is here, and OP didn't seem to concerned about that part.  Generally, yeah, you'd want to do that.  100% required?  Depends on the exact situation.

Comment: Yea, I only put that comment in for the relevant use case. More as an adendum than a dig at you

Comment: I did take that sentence into account as well, though I'm not quite to that point yet @PatrickQ. I've made sure my select tags have names and my option tags have values because I will most likely do it that way, but AJAX could be a possibility.